# Selenium CSS Locator special character @

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

I just wanted to know what does the special character @ means in the selenium CSS locator.

For example, for the HTML

```html
<select id="ms1" multiple="multiple">
    <option id="oa">
     OptionA
    </option>
    <option id="ob" selected="selected">
     OptionB
    </option>
    <option id="oc">
     OptionD
    </option>
</select>
```

I get the following element presence results with different CSS locators-

```py
# s1 is selenium object
>>> s1.is_element_present('css=select[multiple="multiple"][id="ms1"]')
False
>>> s1.is_element_present('css=select[@multiple="multiple"][id="ms1"]')
True
>>> s1.is_element_present('css=select[@multiple="multiple"][@id="ms1"]')
False
>>> s1.is_element_present('css=select[multiple="multiple"][@id="ms1"]')
False
>>>
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@` character has no special purpose in a Selenium CSS selector.  It has special meaning in the Selenium `getAttribute` command, but that's not what you're using here.

The correct way to write your seach is:

```
s1.is_element_present('css=select#ms1[multiple="multiple"]')
```

However, since `id` attributes are supposed to be unique, the following ought to work just as well, and probably quicker:

```
s1.is_element_present('css=#ms1')
```

Or even quicker, because no CSS analysis is necessary:

```
s1.is_element_present('id=ms1')
```

Comment: That is a great answer.... What I found is @ has no meaning!! If you provide @ with an locator type, other work takes over and it work!! If both locator types are provided with @, the search fails!! Thanks

Comment: Also is used for media queries for responsive layouts. @media